# Export tree made in unity to another project

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have made a tree in Unity, by creating the gameobject "tree" and then developing it from there. I would now like to move this tree gameobject to another project. I did not find any tutorials. How do i do this?

Thank  you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a unitypackage and then import it in the new project. Assets -> Export Package...

You may need to turn your tree object into a prefab before doing it. Simply drag your tree object to the assets folder in the project view. Or create the prefab first - Create -> Prefab and drag your gameobject into that new file.

Comment: Hello, i tried that, and if i do it, it seems to not work anyways. When i reimport it all i have is a box collider that i had added to the prefab.

Comment: How is your tree made? Can you include a picture of the inspector?

Comment: I went on GameObject - 3d Object - Tree and created a tree, with 1 root, 6 branches that then extend to 236, that have in total 5162 leaves. I have a "mesh" component, "mesh renderer", "Box collider".

Comment: I just realized i has two box colliders. I have no idea why I had two, but by removing one, everything works fine! I upvoted your answer anyway, thank you! :)